# Is it possible to use the Firebase Emulator over USB?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-tools

My Android device is in another network than my development computer. However I can connect my aAdroid device to my computer via USB. Any chance to use the Firebase Emulator in this case? Can it somehow be tunneled over USB?

Comment: Adb supports TCP forwarding between Android and PC in both directions `adb forward` and ` adb reverse`. But it seems like you may have to forward a lot of ports according to the [Firebase emulator port list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#port_configuration). Not sure which one you really need.